# How to split a line in CSV with multiple delimiters into different hashes?

Tags: csv, perl, split, hashmap

File `zone.csv` looks like below:

===========================================================

```
zone0,primaryserver1,primaryserver2,secondaryserver1|secondaryserver2

zone1,primaryserver1,primaryserver2,primaryserver3,secondaryserver1|secondaryserver2|secondaryserver3

zone2,primaryserver1,secondaryserver1

zone3,primaryserver1,primaryserver2,secondaryserver1|secondaryserver2
```

===========================================================

First is the zone, then all primary servers are listed which are comma-separated, then all secondary servers are listed, which are pipe-separated.

I need to fill two hashes (zone + primary server) and (zone + secondary server). I need help with the usage of the `split` function with two delimiters. I want all primary servers in one hash and all secondary servers in another hash (with the zone to be the key for both the hashes). Your help will be much appreciated.

```
        my %zoneP;
        my %zoneS;
        my $file1 = "zone.csv";
        open (IN1, "$file1") || die "Cannot open $file1\n";

        # Read File
        while (<IN1>)
        {
                chomp($_);
                # all regex - avoid comments and empty lines
                if ( ($_ !~ /^(#)+/) && ( $_ =~ /[a-z A-Z 1-9 \. \[ \] \* \+ ]/) )
                {
                        print "$_\n" if($debug > -1);
                        my ($zone, $serverP, $serverS) = split(",",$_);
                        $zoneP{$zone} = $serverP;
                        $zoneS{$zone} = $serverS;

                }
        }
        close IN1;
```

I wrote the above code but need help with the split function - how to use two delimiters and get values in separate hashes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `split` twice: first with the comma, then with the pipe.

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my %zoneP;
my %zoneS;

# Read File
while (<DATA>) {
    chomp($_);
    # all regex - avoid comments and empty lines
    if ( ($_ !~ /^(#)+/) && ( $_ =~ /[a-z A-Z 1-9 \. \[ \] \* \+ ]/) )
    {
        my ($zone, @servers) = split(/,/, $_);
        my $server_s = pop @servers;
        my @servers_s = split(/\|/, $server_s);
        push @{ $zoneP{$zone} }, [@servers];
        push @{ $zoneS{$zone} }, [@servers_s];
    }
}

print "zoneP\n";
use Data::Dumper; $Data::Dumper::Sortkeys=1; print Dumper(\%zoneP);
print "zoneS\n";
use Data::Dumper; $Data::Dumper::Sortkeys=1; print Dumper(\%zoneS);

__DATA__
zone0,primaryserver1,primaryserver2,secondaryserver1|secondaryserver2

zone1,primaryserver1,primaryserver2,primaryserver3,secondaryserver1|secondaryserver2|secondaryserver3

zone2,primaryserver1,secondaryserver1

zone3,primaryserver1,primaryserver2,secondaryserver1|secondaryserver2
```

Output:

```
zoneP
$VAR1 = {
          'zone0' => [
                       [
                         'primaryserver1',
                         'primaryserver2'
                       ]
                     ],
          'zone1' => [
                       [
                         'primaryserver1',
                         'primaryserver2',
                         'primaryserver3'
                       ]
                     ],
          'zone2' => [
                       [
                         'primaryserver1'
                       ]
                     ],
          'zone3' => [
                       [
                         'primaryserver1',
                         'primaryserver2'
                       ]
                     ]
        };
zoneS
$VAR1 = {
          'zone0' => [
                       [
                         'secondaryserver1',
                         'secondaryserver2'
                       ]
                     ],
          'zone1' => [
                       [
                         'secondaryserver1',
                         'secondaryserver2',
                         'secondaryserver3'
                       ]
                     ],
          'zone2' => [
                       [
                         'secondaryserver1'
                       ]
                     ],
          'zone3' => [
                       [
                         'secondaryserver1',
                         'secondaryserver2'
                       ]
                     ]
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this demonstrates how to parse that file format. Hopefully the #comments explain it.

```
my(%zoneP,%zoneS);
while(<DATA>){
  chomp;                                     #no newline
  s/\s*#.*//;                                #no #comments and whitespace before them
  next if !/\S/;                             #skip empty lines, no non-whitespace
  my($zone,@servers) = split /,/;            #split into zone and servers
  $zoneS{$zone} = [split /\|/, pop@servers]; #secondary server(s) are behind last comma
  $zoneP{$zone} = [@servers];                #primary are the ones left after pop above
}

use Data::Dumper; print Dumper \%zoneP, \%zoneS;

__DATA__
#comment1

zone0,primaryserver1,primaryserver2,secondaryserver1|secondaryserver2 #comment 2
zone1,primaryserver1,primaryserver2,primaryserver3,secondaryserver1|secondaryserver2|secondaryserver3
zone2,primaryserver1,secondaryserver1
zone3,primaryserver1,primaryserver2,secondaryserver1|secondaryserver2
```

The second split escapes the `|` char since that char have a special meaning in regexes. It's perhaps easy to forget that the first argument of split is always a regexp so to make that more readable and clear I think `/\|/` is always better here than `'\|'` even if that would work as well. `"\|"` however wouldn't work since that's equivalent of `'|'` not `'\|'`.

Output:

```
$VAR1 = {
      'zone3' => [
                   'primaryserver1',
                   'primaryserver2'
                 ],
      'zone0' => [
                   'primaryserver1',
                   'primaryserver2'
                 ],
      'zone1' => [
                   'primaryserver1',
                   'primaryserver2',
                   'primaryserver3'
                 ],
      'zone2' => [
                   'primaryserver1'
                 ]
    };
$VAR2 = {
      'zone3' => [
                   'secondaryserver1',
                   'secondaryserver2'
                 ],
      'zone0' => [
                   'secondaryserver1',
                   'secondaryserver2'
                 ],
      'zone1' => [
                   'secondaryserver1',
                   'secondaryserver2',
                   'secondaryserver3'
                 ],
      'zone2' => [
                   'secondaryserver1'
                 ]
    };
```

Answer (score -1):

There's no reason to split twice, just split with a Regex `or` match:

```perl
my ($zone, @servers) = split(/,|\|/, $_);

say $zone;
say Dumper(@servers);
```

```
zone1
$VAR2 = 'primaryserver1';
$VAR3 = 'primaryserver2';
$VAR4 = 'primaryserver3';
$VAR5 = 'secondaryserver1';
$VAR6 = 'secondaryserver2';
$VAR7 = 'secondaryserver3';
```